# Issue with handleCategoryClick and handleSearchChange in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm working on a React app where I have implemented two functions, **`handleCategoryClick`** and **`handleSearchChange`**, to handle category selection and search functionality, respectively. On the landing page, both functions work perfectly. However, when navigating to another page, the functionality is not retained.

Specifically, when I click on a category using **`handleCategoryClick`**, the search functionality provided by **`handleSearchChange`** only works within the selected category and does not apply to all categories. I want the search functionality to work across all categories, regardless of the selected category.

I have ensured that the state variables **`selectedCategory`** and **`searchTerm`** are properly updated when navigating to a different page, but the issue persists. I suspect there might be an issue with how the filtering is performed in the **`filteredCards`** array.

I have provided the relevant code snippet above for reference. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried debugging the code and exploring possible solutions to resolve the issue. Specifically, I have:

- Reviewed the implementation of **`handleCategoryClick`** and **`handleSearchChange`** functions to ensure they are correctly updating the state variables **`selectedCategory`** and **`searchTerm`** respectively.
- Checked that the filtering logic in the **`filteredCards`** array is correctly implemented to include all categories when **`selectedCategory`** is null or "All".
- Examined the code for any potential conflicts or inconsistencies that might affect the functionality.

I expected that when navigating to another page, the selected category would be retained and the search functionality would work across all categories. However, the search functionality only operates within the selected category, and when navigating away from the landing page, the functionality is lost.

Despite my efforts, I have been unable to resolve the issue. I'm looking for guidance and suggestions on how to make the search functionality work consistently across all categories, even when navigating to different pages.

```
//App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'
import filteredData from './components/data/filteredData';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const itemsPerPage = 9;
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

   const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  }; 

  const handleCategoryClick = (category) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
    const { category, text, description } = item;
    const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    return (
      (!selectedCategory || selectedCategory === 'All' || category === selectedCategory) &&
      ( category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) || 
        text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
        description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
    );
  });

  const totalCards = filteredCards.length;
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCards / itemsPerPage);

  const indexOfLastCard = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstCard = indexOfLastCard - itemsPerPage;
  const currentCards = filteredCards.slice(indexOfFirstCard, indexOfLastCard);
  const pageNumbers = Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, i) => i + 1);


  return (
    <Router>
    <div>        
      {selectedCategory === null && (
        <div className="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white" style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff)', marginTop: '20px' }}>
          Mas Verificaciones
        </div>
      )}
      
      <div className="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2 custom-class1">
        <nav className="nav d-flex justify-content-between px-3">
        <h2><a href="/"><img src="logo.png"  alt=" "/></a></h2>          
          {["Estados Unidos", "Mexico", "America Latina", "Resto del Mundo", "Covid-19", "Salud", "Medio Ambiente", "Guerra en Ucrania"].map((cat) => (
            <span
            className={`nav-link-second p-2 d-none d-md-block ${selectedCategory === cat ? "active" : ""}`}
            key={cat}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => handleCategoryClick(cat)}
          >
            {cat}
          </span>
          ))}
        </nav>
      </div>
      
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search..."
              value={searchTerm}
              onChange={handleSearchChange}             
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>   
  
            
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
           element={
                <>
                  <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                      {currentCards.map((item) => (
                        <div className="col-md-4 mb-3" key={item.id}>
                          <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">
                              <div className="frame-color"></div>
                              <p className="card-text">{item.category}</p>
                              <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>
                              <Link to="/testing" className="btn btn-primary">
                                {item.text}
                              </Link>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>

        <nav aria-label="...">
          <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
            <li className={`page-item ${currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
              <a
                className="page-link"
                href="#"
                onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}
                tabIndex="-1"
              >
                Previous
              </a>
            </li>
            {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
              <li
                key={number}
                className={`page-item ${currentPage === number ? 'active' : ''}`}
              >
                <a
                  className="page-link"
                  href="#"
                  onClick={() => setCurrentPage(number)}
                >
                  {number}
                </a>
              </li>
            ))}
            <li
              className={`page-item ${
                currentPage === totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''
              }`}
            >
              <a
                className="page-link"
                href="#"
                onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}
              >
                Next
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>       
      </>
    }
  />

<Route path="/testing" element={<Testing /> } /></Routes>
      <Footer />
      
    </div>
    
    </Router>
    
    
  
  );
}
 function Testing() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
     
    </div>
  );
}  


export default App;
```

Comment: You could explore moving this functionality into a React Context. That way all children of the context could have access to the data and it wouldn't be lost when navigating.

https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Answer (score 0):

> I want the search functionality to work across all categories,
> regardless of the selected category.

For this you'll want to change the logical AND (*`&&`*) to a logical OR (*`||`*) so that ***regardless of*** the selected category value, array elements that ***also*** happen to match via the search string are also included in the filtered result array.

Change the following code from:

```js
const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
  const { category, text, description } = item;
  const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return (
    (!selectedCategory ||
      selectedCategory === "All" ||
      category === selectedCategory) && // <-- this conditional
    (category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
  );
});
```

to

```js
const filteredCards = filteredData.filter((item) => {
  const { category, text, description } = item;
  const lowerCaseSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return (
    (!selectedCategory ||
      selectedCategory === "All" ||
      category === selectedCategory) || // <-- be more inclusive
    (category.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      text.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm) ||
      description.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseSearchTerm))
  );
});
```

I don't have any of your data so I had to make it up, but here's a running demo:

[image: Edit issue-with-handlecategoryclick-and-handlesearchchange-in-react-app]

> I expected that when navigating to another page, the selected category
> would be retained and the search functionality would work across all
> categories. However, the search functionality only operates within the
> selected category, and when navigating away from the landing page, the
> functionality is lost.

I was unable to reproduce any issues cause by (A) changing the next/previous page, or (B) navigating to `"/testing"` and back to `"/"`. All state and filtering/search results remained as expected.

Comment: I switched the logical operator from AND (&&) to OR (||), but it did not work, this is my const filteredData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    category: "Mexico",
    pagePath: "/articles/1",
    text: "Learn More",
    description: "loren ipsum loren ipssum loren ipsum"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    category: "Estados Unidos",
    pagePath: "/testing/1",
    text: "Learn More",
    description: "loren ipsum loren ipssum loren ipsum"
  },]

Comment: @Ancarsa95 If you copy in *your* `filteredData` value into my sandbox, is the filtering and search functionality working as expected? I'd say it is from what you describe wanting it to do. If that's not the case can you edit your post to more clearly describe what the issue is and provide exact reproduction steps that should help illustrate the discrepancy between expected and observed behavior?

Comment: both functions work as expected in the landing page, however once I navigate to another component I reuse the search bar and nav-scroller then the search functionality is not retained nor the handlecategoryClick

Comment: @Ancarsa95 Can you edit your post to include this other code then, and clarify where and how you are navigating to another component, e.g. exact reproduction steps? Like I said, in my sandbox (*copy/pasted your code*) I could navigate to the other route and back and all the state and search/filter results remained as expected.

Comment: I check your sandbox but the search bar is not working,

Comment: I posted the question again, hopefully you can help me, thanks for your time

Comment: @Ancarsa95 Can you clarify what exactly isn't working with the search in the sandbox? Are you saying that when on one of the other pages and the user interacts with the search you want the UI to navigate back to the "landing page" so the search results are rendered? Or do you ***not*** want to conditionally render the search results on ***only*** the "landing page"?